# Is it possible to use EF codefirst database initialisers in Migrator .NET migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, migratordotnet

I'm using Migrator.NET to manage schema changes on our production environment. Because I've been using EF code-first, all development to the database has been incremental to the code-first classes and no migrations have been applied to the project.

However, I'd like to be able to start using migrations once the project is in a production environment. As the baseline 'up' migration, I'd like to use code-first's database initializer to create the database and prime with default data. However, I'm having problems because the EF context classes and my wrapper classes for EF initializers are in .NET 4, whereas migrator .NET is using .NET 2.

When running the migrator console app, I'm getting 'This assembly is built by runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime...'

Am I expecting to much for this to work? I could use OSQL and create the SQL script on the server, but it would be nice if this worked just as it does in the development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Weird. Even if the migratordotnet binary is in .NET 2 you should be able to use it. I worked on a project where we did just this. We used EF Code First to automatically generate the schema if it didn't exist, otherwise we would run the migrations to the existing one (we started creating the migration steps while still in the dev phase).

Comment: I don't tink I you can mix .NET versions of libraries. Its ok if they are in separate assemblies but not if I want my client assembly to be in .NET2 (migrator classes) and access .NET4 assemblies. I may be wrong...